# Avoid Click event if mouse moved on div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

Is there any (css or dom) property that could be set on a DIV element or any other clean/standard way to avoid firing a click event when the mouse is moved after the mousedown?

Suppose there is one div element within another div. The goal is to prevent the click event on the parent also when the mouse is moved on its (smaller) descendant (to avoid event handling on descendants).

With no prevention, mousedown + mousemove + mouseup fires a click event.

The goal is either kind of mousemove "aborts" the mousedown on the element or prevents the click after mouseup

Comment: Test co-ordinates(`event.clientX/Y`) over `mouse-down` and `mouse-up` events..

Comment: Thought about that but it requires adding extra handlers to each element and changing the click handler itself. Moreover, if a descendant element catches the mousedown that won't work anymore, would it?

Comment: see if I understood. You wan't to choose between clicking and canceling a click if you move after mouse down? Just pass a flag parameter with the eventHandler function. `mousedown` turns flag on, `mousemove` turns flag off

Comment: That flag parameter seems worth an answer with a code example, even though it does not sound like a "clean" solution :) http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/147983